# Camera set / scene setup

Tags: camera, scene

Why is the camera alway tilted sideways, upside-down, and at an angle?  Not exaggerating either. When I try to render a scene the camera is always off-kilter, and the scene renders at a great distance, not as viewed through the camera lens.

I obviously don't know what to do. Help please.

Comment: Congrats on asking the 60,000th question

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite ridiculous, but your scene might actually be upside-down. If this is the case, just select all your objects, and rotate them 180 degrees on the Y axis. You can also rotate your camera to be upside-down the same way if your scene is to large to be entirely rotated. If the scene is not the problem, look at the camera settings. The view might be distorted, or the camera you are moving may not be the active camera.

Comment: Think I have orientation corrected and camera zoom fixed. Thanks for the responce.